# Passing timestamp to a form on button click

Tags: javascript, html

Very new to Javascript. I would like to pass a timestamp to a form when the user clicks a button, but I'm having trouble with getting the actual value to submit.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dateOfUser = new Date();
    document.getElementById("userdate").value = dateOfUser;
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

// hide the content from user until they click the button
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
     $("#ans").show();
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<p>
   Click the button to see the text.
</p>

<p><button type="button" id="show" onclick="userdate = new Date()">Show text</button></p>

<div id="ans" style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" id="userdate" name="timestamp" value="dateOfUser">
Here is the hidden text. 
</div>  

</body>
```

I've omitted the form submission code - unfortunately I did not write it and I don't have access to the code beyond using it for form submission.

But upon submission, the .csv file contains:

`"timestamp":"dateOfUser"`

And not the value of "userdate". As far as I understand, using `document.getElementById("userdate").value = dateOfUser;` should allow me to use "userdate" in the HTML.

Any help would be appreciated, I've poured over many similar questions on this site and others, but I am having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Provide an actual event handler, not clear how to help you now. Anyway, you have to pass a date when submit is clicked. Now it's being set on page init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove the `type="hidden"` to test. At least it works for me using `userdate.value`.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p>
   Click the button to see the text.
</p>

<p><button type="button" id="show">Show text</button></p>

<div id="ans" style="display:none">
<input id="userdate" name="timestamp" value="dateOfUser">
Here is the hidden text. 
</div>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

// hide the content from user until they click the button
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
     $("#ans").show();
     $("#userdate")[0].value = new Date()
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

The way you put `script` above the body

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dateOfUser = new Date();
    document.getElementById("userdate").value = dateOfUser;
</script>
```

wouldn't work because the dom(i.e. the elements) has not loaded. While `onclick` and `$(document).ready` are different from the above way.

However, it's still better for you to put `script` at the bottom of body.

Comment: Well, `$("#userdate")[0].value = Date.now()` might be more sensible.

Comment: ```Date.now()``` does not give me anything but gibberish numbers, but ```new Date()``` works! Thanks so much for the help!